# t.createDocumentFragment is not a function - parseHTML - JQuery 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently upgraded from JQuery 1.9 to 3.3.1 and am getting an error in some of my old code relating to the $.parseHTML() function.

[The docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) state some changes in the behavior of this function but shouldn't effect my usage.

I'm trying to ajax GET a view, parse it, append it to modal content, and then show the modal.

```
success: function(editView){
     //GETTING ERROR AT THE BELOW LINE
     var html = $.parseHTML(editView, $('.modal-edit-content'), true);
     //load editView into the modal content tag
     $('.modal-edit-content').html('');
     $('.modal-edit-content').append(html);
}...
```

This is the error:

> jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: t.createDocumentFragment is not a function

The code was working correctly in JQuery 1.9. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: The context given should only be a document element.  `$('.modal-edit-content'),` is not a document element.  Ref. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/

Comment: `$('.modal-edit-content').html(editViiew);` parses html by default